# How to check fsck results, ran at boot, on remote machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fsck

I did `touch /forcefsck && reboot` on remote machine, using Ubuntu 9.10.

How I can find out if there were any errors corrected? How I can find out what the result of the fsck was?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look in `/var/log/fsck/`

Comment: Unfortunately nothing there - time stamps don't match and both files contain this: 
`(Nothing has been logged yet.)`

Comment: These clowns think it's a wishlist bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/513644

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it might be in `/var/log/boot.log`. At least there appears to be something in mine relating to a successful fsck:

```
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
/dev/sda1: clean, 300236/4358144 files, 6740064/17401600 blocks
```

This is on Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Nope, same as above. In fact, I checked the whole `/var/log` and can't see anything to make sense. Now, few days are passed, but still... Thanks!

Comment: to confirm: on CentOS 6.5 restarted with `shutdown -rF now` you can find lines in `/var/log/boot.log` (same as on Ubuntu), such as: Checking filesystems
sys: clean, 119622/5931008 files, 4238482/23716355 blocks...

Answer (score 1):

I was lucky with:

`grep fsck /var/log/*|less`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My distro is Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS x86_64

I found the log you and I need in /var/log/kern.log.

After a black-out during a storm I rebooted my pc with /forcefsck.
My root partition is /dev/sda5.
My /var/log/kern.log below:

```
Aug 15 10:34:40 utopia kernel: [   12.383204] EXT3-fs (sda5): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
Aug 15 10:34:40 utopia kernel: [   12.383209] ext3_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3720218
Aug 15 10:34:40 utopia kernel: [   12.383232] ext3_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3720217
```

... and after some rows like these ...

```
Aug 15 10:34:40 utopia kernel: [   12.441253] EXT3-fs (sda5): 54 orphan inodes deleted
Aug 15 10:34:40 utopia kernel: [   12.441314] EXT3-fs (sda5): recovery complete
Aug 15 10:34:40 utopia kernel: [   12.596464] EXT3-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
```